# Current mirror configuration analysis in LM393

Tags: integrated-circuit, comparator, current-mirror

I've been trying to figure out how this comparator (LM393) works.

So far I can recognize the sections:

- Q8, Q9, Q10, Q12 form the differential amplifier.
- Q15 and Q16 are the output transistors.
- Q1, F1 and Q2 turn off Q3, so they work as a current limiter?
- And Q3, Q4, Q5, Q6 and Q14 are the current mirror.

I'm having problems trying to figure out how this current mirror works. The current through Q3 is mirrored in Q4, Q5, Q6 and Q14. Still, I can't figure out **what is the role of R4**. I've never seen a resistor connected in that way to the base of the transistor; it's different from R2 which balances the current mirrored in Q5. Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

[image: LM393 comparator schematic]

Comment: Look here https://wiki.analog.com/university/courses/electronics/text/chapter-11 fig.11.6

Comment: I found this http://application-notes.digchip.com/006/6-8765.pdf As you can see the "Current Mirror Biasing Circuit" used by the National Semiconductor is different than used by ST.

Comment: It's interesting how different manufacturers have different implementations of the same device. TI datasheets only show the simplified schematics, but that application note explained a lot. Thank you, G36. I'll edit the post soon and mark it as solved.

Comment: Maybe the ST does not want to infringe on the National Semiconductor patent.

Comment: @G36 A patent from 40+ years ago? Since, presumably, that's when NSC would have patented anything related to this hip chip :)

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I understand it:

R4 compensates for limited beta of the output transistors. The base current of all the output transistors bypasses Q3's emitter, as it flows directly into the collector. VBE of Q3 is thus smaller than it should be due to lower emitter current. This VBE in turns controls the output transistors' currents, and sets them lower than in an ideal mirror, due to this insufficient VBE.

Adding R4 allows Q3's collector to go lower than its insufficient VBE would otherwise allow, and thus restores the output currents to where they should be. Q3's VBE is lower than VBE of output transistors, and their currents can thus be higher as well.

The multiple output transistors' base currents cumulatively rob emitter current of Q3, and thus a compensation scheme is more urgent than with a single-output current mirror.

The compensation's effect is best controlled when the output current gains are low. In this case, all output current gains are 1 or less, and thus the compensation is quite effective. Note that R2 lowers the current gain of Q5, perhaps in proportion to Q5.re/R2.

F1 + Q2 is a startup circuit that drives Q2's collector, allowing Q2 VBE to develop, and drive Q1 into conduction. As soon as Q1 starts up, F1 and Q2 shuts down and are effectively out of the circuit, save for parasitic capacitances.